# Interacting between JSP page and Java object?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am working on a project that runs a java back-end and has a web page UI.Basically, the java system runs in on the server and keeps a log of rules that are created in the web page. What I need it to do is take inputs from the text fields on the web page and call a function to pass them to the java object to create a new rule. I also need to be able to call a function to return an array of the rule objects I have created so I can build a table of them on the web page.

I have the UI built as a JSP page and the back-end java classes and functions are all built but I am lost as to how to connect the two.

This is my first attempt at creating a system like this and I have never written anything with Java EE or JSP before.

What I was thinking I could do would be to call a java function when I click the "submit" button to add a new rule and pass the field values to it. I had the same feeling for when I click a button to display the current rules, calling a java function to get the array of objects back and build it into a table.

Does anyone have any insight onto this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please look in to Java servlets as a starting point. There are a zillion different ways to go about this, from very simple (servlets) to rather complex (particularly when things break).

Answer (score 0):

As Dave Newton said, there are various ways to deal with that. The easiest one is to use an Web Framework. You can Google `Java Web Framework` or read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742223/what-is-the-most-commonly-used-java-web-framework).

If you are looking for something to work with JSP, lightweight and very easy to use, I would go for [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to know if you can create objects of the backend Java classes in JSP  and call functions of these objects. For that you can use:

**scriplet tag** `<% any java code in between%>`

```
<% A a=new A();
a.funtion_of_class_A();%>
```

To display the content you can use expression tag.

```
<%=a.someotherfuntion()%>
```

You can use directives to import and initialize and define the variables

```
<%@ page import="com.a" %>
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to put [Java code in JSP pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: Exactly, +1 for GriffeyDog's comment. That is why web frameworks like Spring MVC, JSF, Struts2, etc are so popular. They help you to decouple your presentation logic from your business logic.